# Using java to fetch a web page and handle </b> tag with new line

Tags: java, html

I am able to fetch the website content with the function as in the following:

```
try {
      connection =  new URL("http:xxx???.com").openConnection();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
      scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
      content = scanner.next();

    }catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, the page contains the tag
    < /b >
which is used for getting to the next line, in this case, 
how can I recognize this tag in my java and entering a newline in java code?

thanks

Comment: What is the type of 'content'? Is it a String? Maybe you could then split the String into an array. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish? Just to insert a newline after the </b>?

Comment: yes, the type of content is String.  and yes, I am trying to insert a new line after the </b>. thank you.

Comment: Why would you use </b> for new line, when HTML uses <br /> for this purpose?

Comment: yes, correct. I am trying to extract the content without html tag. I've found out that Jsoup can help do complete this. However, I need to handle when the content  goes to the new line. The tag is </br>

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do when you encounter this tag ("<br />") but you can probably do something like 'content = content.replaceAll("<br/>", "XXX");' where XXX is whatever you want to replace the tag with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int index = content.indexOf("</b>");
System.out.println(index);

String temp1 = content.substring(0, index + 4);
System.out.println(temp1);

String temp2 = content.substring(index + 4);
System.out.println(temp2);

String withNL = temp1 + "\n" + temp2;
System.out.println(withNL);
```

Although there may be a simpler solution; I don't know your full requirements. I print out things so you can see what's going on.